# How can i make a laravel api admin/user login role authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-passport

Im making a api with laravel 9 about a fitness app. This app will have 2 roles Admin and Normal user. What im struggling with is making an Authentication system for the users, so that an Admin can have access to certain routes that a normal user wont. To do that i created a middleware called AdminMiddleware

```
    {
            if(Auth::check()){

                //if admin role = 1
                $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
                if(Auth::user()->role == 1){
                    return $next($request);
                    
                }   
                else{
                    return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Access Denied');
                }
            }
            else{
                return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Log In to gain access');
            }


        return $next($request);

    }
```

This checks whether the user is an admin or not.

This is the routes where the middleware is used

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin'])->get('/admin', function () {
    Route::post('/addProducts', [ProductController::class, 'store']);
    Route::delete('/deleteProducts/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'destroy']);  
    
    Route::post('/addRecipe', [RecipeController::class, 'store']);
    Route::put('/updateRecipe/{id}', [RecipeController::class, 'update'], function (Request $id) {
        return 'Recipe '.$id;
    });
    Route::delete('/deleteRecipe/{id}', [RecipeController::class, 'destroy']);

    

    Route::post('/addEvent', [SpecialEventsController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('event/{id}', [SpecialEventsController::class, 'show'], function (Request $id) {
        return 'Events '.$id;
    });
    Route::put('/updateEvent/{id}', [SpecialEventsController::class, 'update'], function (Request $id) {
        return 'Recipe '.$id;
    });
    Route::delete('/deleteEvent/{id}', [SpecialEventsController::class, 'destroy']);  
    

});
```

And this is the Login Controller, where im having my problems:

```
public function login(Request $request)
            {

                //(Auth::guard('api')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
                if(Auth::guard('api')(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){ 
                    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
                    if($user){
                        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
                        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
                        $success['role'] =  $user->role;
                        return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User login successfully.');
                    }
                    else{
                        return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    return $this->sendError('Unauthorised.', ['error'=>'Unauthorised']);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is returning

```
Error: Object of type Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard is not callable in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Ritwell-App - Copy (2)\app\Http\Controllers\API\RegisterController.php on line 52
```

The part

```
Auth::guard('api')(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
```

was originally

```
if(Auth::attempt
```

but that code gave me an exception

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard::attempt does not exist. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Ritwell-App - Copy (2)\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 113
```

I tried using resources online to help with answers but this is what i could come up with so far and it isnt working.

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong and what is missing in my code?

Comment: What namespace is the LoginController defined in?
Does it make a difference wether you use `Auth` vs `\Auth`?

Comment: Well it should be `Auth::guard('api')->attempt()`, not `Auth::attempt` or `Auth::guard('api')()`, which is trying to call `Auth::gaurd('api')` which ofcourse won't work if doesn't return a callable. I'm just wondering why you are using the `api` guard, and not something like an `admin` guard. Could you show which guards you provided in the `config/auth.php`?

Comment: ```'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],```

Comment: I haven't created any other custom guards